# Unable to display image from cordova.file.documentsDirectory

Tags: ionic-framework

I am trying to access an image that i download from remote server. My code to download the file is as below :

```
var targetPath = cordova.file.documentsDirectory + propp+".png";
var trustHosts = true;


$cordovaFileTransfer.download(url, targetPath, options, trustHosts)
.then(function(result) {
        console.log("Local file transfer done");
        r = angular.toJson(result.nativeURL);
}, function(err) {
    // Error
    console.log("error");
});
```

Then I stored tatgetPath in my local sqlite database. In another page I get this from sqlite and try to display with img tag. But it display like broken Image on Emulator as well as on actual device.

My file url is :
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F7B3169B-D8E3-4F62-AD0B-37CFA381F1CC/Documents/home_bg_image.png

I want to display this image as a background image bit I don't understand how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

After downloading the image you have to paste it in platform/android/assets/www/img-- folder to display the image as

```
var filedirPath = $ionicPlatform.is('android') ?  '/android_asset/www/img/' : 'img';
```

if not find the path of the image and access the file to display for reference please check this link [File path](https://www.airpair.com/ionic-framework/posts/ionic-file-browser-app)
Having any queries reply ..

Comment: Thanks for reply. That tutorial is very good. But i dont understand where and how to use this line. Actually I am new to ionic.